# I can use \refcmpd{a} in \ch{} environment, but not \refcmpd{a.one}?

Tags: chemnum, chemformula

I'm trying to show a reaction with [`chemformula`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula) involving a compound I've named using [`chemnum`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula). If I use `\cmpd{a}` or `\refcmpd{a}` it works fine. However, if I use a sublabel, such as `\refcmpd{a.one}` then it refuses to compile. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? I've included a MWE below: if you uncomment out either of the last to line it suddenly refuses to compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}
\usepackage[]{chemnum}

\begin{document}
\cmpd{a}
\cmpd{a.one}

\refcmpd{a}

\ch{\cmpd{a} -> c}

\ch{\refcmpd{a} -> c}

\refcmpd{a.one}

%\ch{\refcmpd{a.one} -> c} %If you uncomment this it stops compiling.
%\ch{\cmpd{a.one} -> c} %If you uncomment this it stops compiling.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ch{"\refcmpd{a.one}" -> c}` or `\ch{"\cmpd{a.one}" -> c}` should result in the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual of `chemformula`

[image]

And hey, it works!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}
\usepackage[]{chemnum}

\begin{document}
\cmpd{a}
\cmpd{a.one}

\refcmpd{a}

\ch{\cmpd{a} -> c}

\ch{\refcmpd{a} -> c}

\refcmpd{a.one}

\ch{"\refcmpd{a.one}" -> c}

\ch{"\cmpd{a.one}" -> c}

\ch{'\refcmpd{a.one}' -> c}

\ch{'\cmpd{a.one}' -> c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many examples of escapes in the manuals of `chemformula`, `chemmacros` and `chemnum`.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused since the unescaped form worked without a problem, so I never thought to try escaping it.

Comment: And it turns out that wasn't the problem, but helped me find the real one. Thanks.